# Identification of a protection IC

Tags: identification, protection

I need to find a replacement part for a burnt IC.
It is placed between a MCU and some exposed IO.
It was burned by applying 12V as input when 3V3 was the absolute maximum rating in the datasheet of the device.

I suspect that this IC is a kind of TVS or some protective device. By the way, it worked: the MCU is still alive after the 12V story. But the unknown IC is toasted...

It is ~4mm x ~1.6mm

Here is a picture of that IC (another one that is not toasted. The toasted one has literally blown up):
[image]

We can clearly read :
842
2HC

Does anyone know what it is ?

Comment: assuming the spacing of the through-hole pins on the top of the image being 2.54 mm , ca 4×1.5 mm, @laptop2d?

Comment: Have you tried a diode test with a dmm?

Answer (score 0):

The package is a TDFN-16, I'm pretty sure [CM1238](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/logic-signal-switches-multiplexers-decoders/743?k=16TDFN) made by ON Semi. Do a diode test to (what I'm pretty sure are ground pins on the side) and see if it matches.

[image]

### Schematic for CM1238

[image]